# Finding the intersection

Tags: python, numpy

I want intersection of x and y.Is there any  way i can get output in below format.
I do not want use for loop.Since x can be of very large size.

```
x=np.array([[1, 3, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1], [6, 3, 4, 2]])
y=np.array([1,2,0,9,9])
```

I want output in format:

```
np.array([[1],[1,2],[2]])
```

output can also be list of list.
Also consider a case if y is also 2D(`np.array([[1,2,0,9,9],[1,5,6,8,9]])`) .

Comment: `np.array([[1],[1,2],[2]])` that you want would be a jagged array, which is deprecated by numpy

Comment: Would a list of lists be an acceptable output, given the comment by @AlexeyLarionov ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy `intersect1d`

```
arr = [np.intersect1d(z, y).tolist() for z in x]
print(arr) # [[1], [1, 2], [2]]
```